# Why is this XML attribute showing up twice

Tags: php, xml

In PHP i'm using the following code to put a banner at the top of my website.

```
$eventinfo = simplexml_load_file("eventinfo.xml");
<div id="eventinfo"><?php foreach($eventinfo->children() as $child){ $final =   $child["name"]."...<a href='".$child["adr"]."'>more info...</a>"; }  ?>
</div>
```

The XML doc is available at the following: http://eastsidespeedway.raceresults.co/eventinfo.xml

If you go to http://eastsidespeedway.raceresults.co/index.php you'll see that the more info... link is showing up twice. One with the correct link, and the other with a link to the same page (index.php).

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Also. If you see anything that I'm doing wrong, or you know something that's easier - let me know! This is my first time using XML/PHP so I'm kinda just wingin it. Haha.

Comment: One's going to test.html and another to index.php. What is the value of 'adr' in your test scenario?

Comment: The value of adr is currently www.eastsidespeedway.com/dirt.html (the more info... link). View eastsidespeedway.raceresults.co/eventinfo.xml for the XML Doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work for you

```
<?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://eastsidespeedway.raceresults.co/eventinfo.xml');

$title = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
$link = $doc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//print_r($eventinfo);
?>
<div id="eventinfo">
<?php echo $title->item(0)->getAttribute('name'); ?>
<a href='<?php echo $link->item(0)->getAttribute('adr'); ?>'>More Infoo..</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your source:

> ```
> <div id="eventinfo">5/18/2013 - Al Smiley Memorial...<a href=''>more
> info...</a>...<a href='http://www.eastsidespeedway.com/dirt.html'>more
> info...</a></div>
> ```

You've got two hyperlinks- one href is blank meaning that it will redirect to the current page, check your HTML code first to see if you've accidentally duplicated the element, otherwise look at the construction of your string in the php code

Comment: Here's the construction of the string in PHP.. This is most likely the culprit `<?php foreach($eventinfo->children() as $child){ $final =   $child["name"]."...<a href='".$child["adr"]."'>more info...</a>"; }  ?>`